# In Node.js, referring to one function from another within the same file results in a 'ReferenceError: -function- is not defined' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In a node.js application, attempts to reference one function from within another function in the same file (*index.js*) results in the error, **ReferenceError: familyLookup is not defined**.

The intention is to have the second function, *schedule*, call *familyLookup*. How can I fix this?

*index.js*

```
exports.familyLookup = function(oid, callback){
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.findOne( 
        { _id : oid }, 
        { address: 1, phone: 1 }, 
        function(e, doc){
            console.log(doc);
        }
    )
}


exports.schedule = function(db, callback){
    return function(req, res) {
        var lookup = familyLookup();
        var schedule_collection = db.get('schedule');
        var today = new Date();
        var y = [];

        schedule_collection.find({ date : {$gte: today}},{ sort: 'date' },function(err, docs){
            for ( var x in docs ) {
                var record = docs[x];
                var oid = record.usercollection_id;
                result = lookup(db,oid)
                record.push(lookup(oid));
                y.push(record);
            }

            res.render('schedule', {
                'schedule' : y,
            });
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the key message is **ReferenceError: familyLookup is not defined**. Out of your code, you just defined how it can be used **out** of ur *index.js* via `exports.familyLookup`. In other words, one can use *familyLookup* in other file by:

```
// in foo.js
var index = require('index');
index.familyLookup(fooDB, function(){/*  */});
```

You should define the function `familyLookup()` within the same file then define how to use it out of `index.js`:

```
// define function so that it can be used within the same file
var familyLookup = function(db, callback) {/*...*/}
// this line only defines how to use it out of `index.js`
exports.familyLookup = familyLookup;
```

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. Now, on to solving other issues. I've tried to vote you up, but this being my first question, I do not have enough 'reputation points'. You have my gratitude, and when I get enough points, I will come back to vote you up. Regards.